# appending list output to another -python

Tags: python

I am trying to write output of one list to another and I opened an empty list and did an .append(). How ever it gives me an error? I Have mentioned the error below.

What I need?:

the output of list 1 should be put into list 2, shuffle all the lines in list 2 and write that output to a file called random_lines.

```
def main():
c = int(sys.argv[1])
if c == 1:
    rep()
elif c == 2:
    Line()
```

`def rep():`

```
n = int(sys.argv[2])
m = int(sys.argv[3])
count = 0
with open(sys.argv[4]) as f:
    list1 = random.sample(f.readlines(),n)
    list2 = []
    while (count<m):
        for i in list1:
            list2.append(list1)
            count+=1
            random_lines = random.shuffle(list2)
    with open(sys.argv[5],"w") as outcsv:
            print >> outcsv, ''.join(random_lines)
```

> print >> outcsv, ''.join(random_lines)
>   TypeError: can only join an iterable

What mistake am i making?

Comment: AFAIK `random.shuffle` shuffles the list *in place*: its return type is `None`.

Comment: So what do i change here/? random.shuffle() or lines before that?

Comment: got the answer guys. Just FYI. The function should be  `def rep():
 n = int(sys.argv[2])
 m = int(sys.argv[3])
 count = 0
 with open(sys.argv[4]) as f:
  list1 = random.sample(f.readlines(),n)
  while (count<m):
   list2 = list(list1) * m
   random.shuffle(list2)
   result = ''.join(list2)
   count+=1
   with open(sys.argv[5],"w") as outcsv:
    print >> outcsv,result `